# 英語が残っている: 人間かどうかを証明するポップアップ: Check the CAPTCHA box, and we'll be out of your way

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

確認用URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha

reCAPTCHAの導入で、最後の一文が更新されて英語に戻ってしまっています。

[image: ポップアップ]

Answer (score 1):

訳案:

> 横にある[CAPTCHA](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)のチェックボックスにチェックを付けていただければ、後はもうお邪魔いたしません。

Comment: この案を適用しましたが、ビルド後に確認して下さい。リンク先はコード内なんで、マークダウンで新しいリンク先を入れましたが、このテキストにはマークダウンが適用できるかどうかが不明です。もしチェック後に問題あったら、ご教示ください。